What is the meaning and pronunciation of 为 in 他也因此被网友亲切地称呼为 “汉字叔叔”?
2011年，有人把他的故事放到微博上，引起了广泛关注，他也因此被网友亲切地称呼为 “汉字叔叔”。
This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 21. What is the meaning of 为? Baidu translate says that here it is pronounced wei2, while Google translate disagrees and says that it is pronounced wei4.
So what does it mean and how is it pronounced? Maybe wei4 and it means "to", something like: 不足为外人道???

Depending on the usage, there are two ways to pronounce "为". See the linked page to learn the details -  https://www.zdic.net/hans/%E4%B8%BA

The pronunciation is wéi, and the meaning is as (to act as, to designate as).

2011年，有人把他的故事放到微博上，引起了廣泛關注，他也因此被網友親切地稱呼爲＂漢字叔叔＂。
In 2011, his story was posted on Weibo and went viral, leading to netizens affectionately addressing him as "Uncle Hanzi".


Here are the CC-CEDICT entries for 为:

為 为 [wei2] /as (in the capacity of)/to take sth as/to act as/to serve as/to behave as/to become/to be/to do/by (in the passive voice)/
為 为 [wei4] /because of/for/to/

I would read it(*) as wei2 in the text referred to by the question. You could think of it as meaning something like an "as" in "...is called [as] Hanzi uncle."
CC-CEDICT isn't always correct. It has wei2 in the other example given:

不足為外人道 不足为外人道 [bu4 zu2 wei2 wai4 ren2 dao4] /no use to tell others/let's keep this between ourselves (idiom)/

But according to baidu, it's read as wei4 here.
(*) disclaimer - I'm not a native speaker and my spoken Chinese isn't very good at all.

dROOOze's answer is a better translation and conveys the function of 为 here better.
